# Laravel Passport guuard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, guard, login-attempts

passport guard does not support attempt function to authenticate ?

```
if(auth()->guard('api-partner')->attempt(['email' =>$request->email , 'password' => $request->password]))
        {
            //logged succesfly `your text`
            //create token here 

        }
```

but i have this exception

> BadMethodCallException: Method Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard::attempt does not exist

Comment: Please share the `api-partner` guard and the provider.

Comment: //guard
'partner' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'partners',
        ],


//provider 
'partners' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Partner::class,
        ],